# My template is complaining that the context variable request.META.REQUEST_METHOD is missing. What are the possible causes?

Tags: django

The rendered template contains the following:

```
invalid context variable: 'request.META.REQUEST_METHOD'
```

I printed our `locals()` inside the view and I can clearly see

```
META:{
    'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET',
    ...
}
```

Any ideas on what could cause this ?

Comment: Are you passing a RequestContext to the template or a regular Context? Show us how you render the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your template to receive the `request` object, you will need to render the template with a `RequestContext`.

If you are using [`django.shortcuts.render_to_response`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render_to_response) something like the below:

```
return render_to_response(template_name, dictionary)
```

then you should note that, from the linked docs:

> By default, the template will be rendered with a Context instance

and you will want to instead use the following construct:

```
return render_to_response(template_name, dictionary, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

However, better still would be to use [`django.shortcuts.render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) (introduced in Django 1.3) which uses a `RequestContext` by default, so you can just:

```
return render(request, template_name, dictionary)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you are using [render_to_response()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response) without passing a [context_instance argument](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#id2).

Use [render()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) instead and your problem should be gone.